# Why does this OOP approach feel limited, and how can I fix it?

Tags: java, oop

**EDIT**: There are established best practices in every programming language that are not considered opinion based. An example is keeping implementation details private. You don't have to, but it is the accepted best practice for a host of reasons, and no one is going to argue that this is opinion based. My question was asking if my code violated any such established best practices. The fact that it was closed is a bit silly, but I got great answers from presumably decent people, and I am thankful. I hope their answers help others as well!

I'm trying to wrap my head around an idea:

Let's say I think of a coke machine as an object in Java. In reality, a coke machine has many different inputs (ie: coke button, sprite button, water button, etc). I input my choice, I get out what I asked for. So, my java object should mimic this behavior (at least in my mind).

So to relate this to my problem, I've been tasked to write a class called Counter TWICE. The first part of the assignment was done without object oriented principles, and the second was to re-write it using OOP principles. My OOP solution feels like I am creating a coke machine that only has one kind of drink in it. Each time I want a new flavor, I've got to go find a new machine. Even though it works, This feels very limiting and wrong to me, yet I don't know how to make it "OOP" any other way.

The original version looked something like this (**See explicit question after code**):

```
public class Counter {

    public int[] countChars(String text){
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] counter = new int[26];
        // ... get frequencies of each letter into counter array ...
        return counter;
    }

    public int indexOfChar(char c, String s){
        // ... some code for getting the index of char c in String s
    }


    public int maxIndex(int[] counter){
       // ... some code for finding the index containing the highest value
    }

}
```

So the only way I have come up with to make this thing "object oriented" is like so:

```
public class Counter {

    private final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private final int[] counts = new int[26];
    private String text;

    public Counter(String input){
        text = input;  
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
            char currChar = Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i));
            int alphaDex = ALPHABET.indexOf(currChar);

            if (alphaDex != -1){
                counts[alphaDex] += 1;
            }

        }

    }

    public int indexOfChar(char c){
        // ... some code for finding char c in the field text
    }

    public int maxIndex(){
        // ... some code for finding the index containing highest frequency in the counts array
    }

}
```

**How might I think about this differently, so as to maintain functionality/flexibility of the first way while using the OOP approach of the second way? In Python, I might use default arguments, but that is not an option here. My other thought is to write two versions of every method: one that works on instance variables, and another that works on user chosen arguments. This seems very cumbersome!**

Comment: *"How might I think about this differently, so as to maintain functionality/flexibility of the first way while using the OOP approach of the second way? "* ... OOP is about composing a solution from a problem domain that can be described by objects.  Your solution is entirely procedural and uses no objects at all.  I would say that there is no object-orientation here.

Comment: @scottb that is what I was thinking too. I mostly have coded algorithms for math, and this feels like that... It seems like OOP isn't a good fit, at least the way I understand the definition of OOP. Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't meaning to say that your problem domain can't be described in terms of objects, only that you haven't used any objects in your solution.  This problem can be abstracted to a number of potential objects.  For example, a `SodaMachine` class would represent the Coke machine.  Soda machines have behaviors like `dispenseCan();`, `checkInventoryFor(type);`, and `refundMoney()'`.  Soda machines **have** a number of buttons.  The word "have" is a clue that you could have an abstract `SodaButton` class. This is what I mean by describing a problem domain in terms of objects.

Comment: *" In Python, I might use default arguments, but that is not an option here."* ... actually, it is possible to implement a software solution in Java that offers default arguments.  While it is true that there is no direct linguistic support for default arguments in a method, default arguments can be offered in a few ways: 1) a default value can be applied in response to a `null` argument; or 2) arguments can be specified via a variation of the *Builder Pattern*; or 3) default values can be specified using telescoping signatures in overloaded methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor should just take the `String` and store it.  Then your other methods can work on that stored string when requested.

For the frequency count, why not use a `Map` to count ALL possible characters.  You can then return the map when requested.

```
      Map<Character, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
      freq.compute(c, // character to be counted
            (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 //initialize to 1 on first occurrence
                  : v + 1);  // add 1 for each additional occurrence
```

But you need to decide if you class should be `static methods` (like the `Math` class which cannot be instantiated but works on user supplied input,

Or stored in an internal `instance field`, more similar to the `String` class but with different functionality.

> My OOP solution feels like I am creating a coke machine that only has one kind of drink in it. Each time I want a new flavor, I've got to go find a new machine.

I'm not certain I understand that?  Are you equating `flavors` with different `Strings`?

> My other thought is to write two versions of every method: one that works on instance variables, and another that works on user chosen arguments. This seems very cumbersome!

I tend to agree.

If counter has no other purpose than to do analysis on `Strings` then I would make all the methods static and supply the argument to the method as required.

But if the class has other uses (like `String`) for instance where you would have a `collection` of `Counters` for some other purpose (TBD) then I would have classes that could be instantiated.

Comment: So a static method belongs to the class, not an instance of the class (I just looked it up)... That sounds like what I understand to be functional programming (like the stuff I do for my math classes, just algorithm writing). Is it also considered OOP?

Comment: Yes! I am equating the String input to the flavors of soft drink.

Comment: It is functional programming.   And you could do your class as an Object and operate on it as I first suggested.  But what purpose does a Counter have other than to store a series of characters and then operate on them?  It can be written in OO style but  it isn't used elsewhere (like a String in a hashmap).

Comment: Well, what I am using this "counter" for is to get some information that will help me decode a basic ceaser cipher. It's basically a utility to get some pieces of the puzzle. It seems like I should go with your suggestion of static methods.

Comment: Think of your Counter class as a utility class of sorts.  It provides a related set of methods to facilitate processing of a certain type, all neatly packaged together in a single class.  Nothing at all wrong with that.  And OOP would not be as effective without those types of classes.

Comment: @rocksNwaves Note that a series of static methods would not be accepted as OOP in a classroom type grading situation

Comment: @thatotherguy I suppose I wasn't exactly accurate. I was tasked with writing a Caeser Cipher class in two ways, and I generalized that assignment to this Counter Class I am using to help get that done. But I can see what you mean as to why it wouldn't be accepted.

Comment: The Counter class could be an adjunct to your Caesar Cipher solution.  But I really can't answer if it meets you task requirements.